# Check if table has two values if so then

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have a table called "link-relations" 
and the structure is "id, user_id, link_id"

now i need to check for a record if there is a user_id of "2" and link_id of "1"

something like:

```
if (!mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links_relations WHERE (link_id, user_id) 
VALUES     ('".$link['id']."', '".$user['id']."')")){
   //dosomething
}else{
   //do something else!
}
```

pxl help!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to need to explore the MySQL Documentation to learn the syntax.

The correct syntax for something like that is this:

```
SELECT * FROM `link_relations` WHERE `link_id` = '1' AND `user_id` = '2'
```

Don't rely on copy/pasting these answers. Please go read the documentation!

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

To setup your script, if would look more like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `link_relations` WHERE `link_id` = '1' AND `user_id` = '2'");
if ($result) {
    // Query did not throw an error. Now see if there are results
    $rows = mysql_fetch_all();
    $numRows = count($rows);

} else {
    // Error!
}
```

Also note that the use of mysql_ functions should end now. It is deprecated and going away.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use next code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `links_relations` WHERE `link_id`=1 AND `user_id`=2";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
if ($q and mysql_num_rows($q)>0) {
    // you have required record in the table
}
```

But you really need to read MySQL documentation.